# Foreign key relationship error in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am developing a django app where I use a legacy database. This database doesn't have primary key or constraint in any table. This are two of my models

```
class Provider(models.Model):
    id_provider = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    signed = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'mpc_proveedores'

class Master(models.Model):
    id_provider = models.ForeignKey(Proveedor)
    anio = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    mes = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    nombre_prov = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    tipo_conci = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    f_recepcion = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    e_recepcion = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'mpc_master'
```

I need to show a table based on the model Master and I need to display the name of the provider instead of the id_provider.

This is my view

```
def monitorViewV2(request):
    table = MonitorTable(Master.objects.all())
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request,'monitorv2.html',{'table': table})
```

When I try to see the template in the browser, the next error is showed

> ORA-00904: "MPC_MASTER"."ID_PROVIDER_ID": invalid identifier

I don't know if the error is because I don't have relationships in the database or if I need to create a function in the view to display the name instead of the id_provider.
Can you bring me some snippet or link where I can take some ideas to resolve this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `id_provider` the actual column name on `mpc_master` table?

Comment: Yes, I use Python manage.py inspectdb > models.py

Comment: And converted the `Integer` columns into `ForeignKey`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django needs there to be an integer DB column for foreign key relations, which will hold the PK of the related object. It looks like that column is `id_provider` in this case, so you should specify that in your field declaration. I'd also use a different field name to avoid confusion:

```
provider = models.ForeignKey(Proveedor, db_column='id_provider')
```

The docs provide a little more context:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#database-representation